# Postgres search using lower() index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I have a Postgres table containing column with stings in upper and lower case characters.

```
Table: company
id| name    | department
------------------------
1 | LM Corp | Repair
2 | BMG Inc | Maintenance
3 | DFR LLC | shipping
```

Using pgAdmin I created an index on the column as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX companydepartment_index
ON public.company (lower(department) ASC NULLS LAST);
```

When I do a query where input string is lowercase 'repair' then I don't get a match.

```
select company.id from company where company.department = lower($1));
```

Why isn't Postgres using the lowercase index to match the lowercase string?

I don't want to use: ...where lower(company.department) = lower($1)),  because it defeats the purpose of having a lowercase index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want to use: ...where lower(company.department) = lower($1)), because it defeats the purpose of having a lowercase index.

On the contrary, the index will only be used if you use exactly the same expression in the query as in the index. See [Indexes on Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) in the documentation.

Comment: No, in this case the planner knows that it can use the index. No convertions are done, it just search in the index. In case of `department = $1` it has no option other than seq scan over the table.

Comment: @ Klim But when if I use ...where lower(company.department) = lower($1)), this is not exactly the same expression because index also contains  ASC NULLS LAST. Does expression have to be exactly the same to use the index?

Comment: `ASC NULLS LAST` is not a part of the index expression, see the syntax: [Create Index.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createindex.html)

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
where lower(company.department) = lower($1)),
```

does *not* defeat the purpose of having a lower-case index.  It is *exactly* the reason why you want to have one.  What is important for using the index is the expression `lower(company.department)`, because this is the expression used to build the index.